# How to send notification to a Chrome Web App using Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I created a chrome web app.  The app simply opens my web site.  This is working as expected.  The app is available on the Chrome Web Store.  I am able to add it to Chrome.  The site was existing, so I simply added the url and launch properties in the manifest.json.  I am new to GCM altogether.  I am trying to configure code to send a notification or message to the web app using GCM.  I understand I need to add javascript code to register the app.  The documentation I am reading isn't as straight forward as I would like or understand.  I am a little confused at this part.  I added this to the manifest.json file:

```js
"background": {
      "scripts": ["scripts/main.js"]
    }
```

What is javascript code I would include in the main.js file to register the web app?  Also, can someone tell me what or how that register function is called?  The only files in my package are the manifest.json and main.js files.  Specific examples would be very much appreciated.

I do not need to do anything complex at this time.  I would simply like to test the GCM notification process to a Chrome Web App.  I also understand there is an application server component, but first want to make sure the Web App is configured correctly with the right files and code.

Comment: Here is a relevant sample: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/gcm-notifications

Comment: That was fairly easy to follow and test.  I typed in the 'senderid' and received a 'registrationid'.  I understand this would be the RegistrationId used by the app server to send a message to the client.  I am trying to understand the flow: so when developing the Web App I would register the app to get the RegistrationId.  Would I then upload the Web App to the Web Store.  I would send a message to the client or people who have installed the Chrome Web App using the RegistrationId generated?